# Leak a GOT entry using return-to-printf@plt

Tags: exploit, exploit-development

I have a small binary compiled as non-pie, but ASLR is enabled, so the shared libraries are randomized. My plan was to leak any libc address from GOT via returning to plt, but the only useful  plt-stub i have is a printf. Previously i wrote a working exploit with this method, when i could use puts, but in this case the only output i get after returning to printf@plt is an empty string.

I couldn't find out the reason of this behavior so far; why printf acts like this?
Is it even possible to leak an address this way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it's possible to leak an address using `printf`. In `puts` you only need to pass one argument to the function, the string you want to write to stdout, and in a case of a buffer-overflow the address of the function you want to leak. In `printf` you also need to pass a format specifier. There's a [**write-up here**](https://github.com/VulnHub/ctf-writeups/blob/master/2016/sctf/pwn2.md) that demonstrates exactly that.